# ng-pattern to allow alpha and certain special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

In form - name field I want to do a validation against

- Should allow only Alpha characters
- Allow space
- Allow certain special characters - `_ \ / - . ’`

I tried,

```
 ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+[_+\+/+-+.+’][a-z]*$/"
```

Looks like I have missed out something as its not working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see:

- *Should allow only Alpha characters* => `[a-zA-Z]`
- *Allow space* => `[ ]` or `\s`
- *Allow certain special characters - `_ \ / - . ’ '`*  => `[_\\\/.’'-]`

So, combining all that, the pattern will look like:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z _\\\/.’'-]+$/"
```

This matches 1 or more (`+`) chars from the allowed set.

To disallow leading/trailing whitespace, use

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z_\\\/.’'-]+(?: +[A-Za-z_\\\/.’'-]+)*$/" ng-trim="false"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7sC9nK/2)

The `ng-trim="false"` will prevent from trimming the input sent to the regex engine. The new regex will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_\\\/.’'-]+` - 1 or more letters or allowed symbols other than space
- `(?: +[A-Za-z_\\\/.’'-]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `+` - (or, `\s+`) - 1 or more spaces (whitespaces)
  - `[A-Za-z_\\\/.’'-]+` - see above
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: It failed for name - Dinesh D'Soza

Comment: Then just add the single quote to the character class. Just keep in mind that the hyphen must be at the end, right before `]`.

Comment: Can we restrict leading/trailing whitespace ?

Comment: So, the requirement changed ? :) Yes, it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

`/^([a-z _\/.'-])+$/i` would do. If you want any space character instead of just space, use `/(^[a-z_\/.'-]|\s)+$/i`.

Comment: Your regex will match more than you think. See [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970)